# An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle[...]"

Tags: eclipse, plugins, aptana

I've started using Eclipse Luna with the plugin Aptana Studio 3 and it worked quite well for a while, but after I ran Eclipse as root to update the IDE to version 4.4.1, every time Eclipse starts I get the following error message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle:
>   /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/873/0/.cp/bundles/php.ruble".
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String

I get this error message for the other Aptana bundles as well.

I've tried reinstalling Eclipse and Aptana Studio but nothing has worked yet.
I'd be very glad if someone could help. Sorry for bad english, I'm not a native speaker.

Here's a log sample:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-09-27 19:19:23.753
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle: /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/873/0/.cp/bundles/php.ruble".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.jruby.util.OSEnvironment.getAsMapOfRubyStrings(OSEnvironment.java:90)
    at org.jruby.util.OSEnvironment.getSystemPropertiesMap(OSEnvironment.java:75)
    at org.jruby.RubyGlobal.defineGlobalEnvConstants(RubyGlobal.java:393)
    at org.jruby.RubyGlobal.createGlobals(RubyGlobal.java:358)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.init(Ruby.java:1078)
    at org.jruby.Ruby.newInstance(Ruby.java:186)
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.SingletonLocalContextProvider.getRuntime(SingletonLocalContextProvider.java:95)
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.runParser(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:166)
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:93)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1163)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1223)
    at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingEngine.getInitializedScriptingContainer(ScriptingEngine.java:292)
    at com.aptana.scripting.model.ScriptLoadJob.run(ScriptLoadJob.java:76)
    at com.aptana.scripting.model.AbstractScriptRunner.run(AbstractScriptRunner.java:144)
    at com.aptana.scripting.model.AbstractScriptRunner.run(AbstractScriptRunner.java:180)
    at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingEngine.runScript(ScriptingEngine.java:274)
    at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingEngine.runScript(ScriptingEngine.java:243)
    at com.aptana.scripting.model.BundleManager.loadScript(BundleManager.java:2032)
    at com.aptana.scripting.model.BundleManager$BundleLoadJob.run(BundleManager.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: I'm having this problem as well, but on Windows using Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and the Aptana Studio plugin 3.6.0.201407100643. It seems to be throwing warnings on start when it tries to load my "rubles." I've yet to find a solution.

Comment: i'm having this issue as well using eclipse 4.4.0 ...

Answer (score 33):

I had the same issue.
Building from the previous post, and in case it was missed, the Eclipse team has [already provided a patch](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122#c51):

Steps to apply patch:

1. Open Eclipse > Help > Install New Software
2. In "Work with:" field, enter http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/
3. From the populated list, select   Eclipse 4.4.1 Patches for bug 445122   . Click "Next"
4. Let Eclipse perform the needed checks. Click "Next"
5. In "Install Details" screen, click "Next"
6. Finish the patch installation process and restart Eclipse.

The problem on my Eclipse was gone after this.
In Win7 I am using: 
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Build id: 20140925-1800

Comment: Just applied this approach today and it worked for me as well.

Comment: Worked for me, Eclipse 4.4.1 on Mac OS X, after installing Aptana Studio.

Comment: Thank you! This answer should be marked as the solution!

Answer (score 8):

I updated the aptana plug-in to 3.7 dev version and the bundle error message dissapeared and it showed the standar aptana start page. Here the link to update it:
http://studio-jenkins.appcelerator.org/job/studio3-feature-development/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/dist/
Now I hope that version works. 
Definitely there was a compatibility between eclipse luna 4.4 and aptana plugin 3.6.

Comment: For me, it works like a charm with 3.7 now. Thank you vicgibcn.       TIPP: If you download the Data from this site via "download as Zip", extract the zip, and look into index.html to see additional Instructions, how to install this Plugin from this Zip-File.

Comment: This also solves problem with horizontal bars which 3.6 had.. annoying flickering has gone.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by updating the IVYDE plugin to the latest build version: https://builds.apache.org/job/IvyDE-updatesite/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/build/

This updates ivy to the 2.5 version and ivyde to the 2.3 version

Comment: Hey, do you mind explaining the process with a bit more detail? I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with that link.

Comment: Just go to [Help]->[Install new Software]->[Available software sites] and update or create the [update site] of the ivyde plugin with https://builds.apache.org/job/IvyDE-updatesite/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/build/

Answer (score 3):

Do the following:

1. In EclipsegGo to the "Help" menu and select "Install New Software"
2. Work with: https://builds.apache.org/job/IvyDE-updatesite/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/build/, then click "Add"
3. A popup window opens, enter name: Ivy Update Site, Click "OK"
4. Wait while it shows "pending"
5. Click Select All to select "Apache Ivy Library" and "Apache IvyDE Eclipse plugins"
6. Hit Next on the next two screens, then accept the license and click "Finish"
7. If you get a warning about unsigned code, click "OK"
8. When propmpted to restart eclipse, click "OK"

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The message for missing bundles are still appear.

Answer (score 1):

The class cast exception is a regression in Eclipse 4.4.1 (Luna SR1) Equinox component:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122

As a number of components were broken by that (Apache IvyDE is just one of them), I plan to avoid using this version of Eclipse and will wait for the next one (SR2).