# Exception starting eclipse luna (SR1) on OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos

When starting eclipse I get the following error on mac

```
01:37:17 ~/Downloads/eclipse$ ./Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /Users/ben/Development/workspace.luna2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.5.0.20140606-0033.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

This is from a fresh download of `eclipse-java-luna-SR1-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz` anyone else having the same issue?

I'm not getting any output in my console windows within eclipse, assuming it's related to the above error.

Comment: Please report that bug to Eclipse bugtracker: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e

Comment: bug logged: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445687

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [question 26077296](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26077296/4116988)

The class cast exception is a regression in Eclipse 4.4.1 (Luna SR1) Equinox component: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122

A number of components were broken by that.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround which saved a lot of headache for me, because eclipse wont start at all.

Adding the following lines to eclipse.ini helped.

```
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.home
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=null
```

and then ./eclipse -clean

Then make an update from the menu Help.

and then simply run eclipse, the way you were doing till now.