# Getting rid of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 that cannot be casted to String

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, ivy, ivyde

I have just run into the Apache Ivy bug `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String` ([link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1487)) when performing Ant task `ivy:config`

This morning I tried to install LibraryFolder [ClasspathContainer](http://libcontainer.sourceforge.net/) plugin into my Eclipse (STS 3.6.1): installing it caused the above error every time I tried to perform `ivy:retrieve`.

Even worse, I tried to install `IvyDE` plugin from Eclipse Marketplace and Eclipse started to crash at a multitude of errors, including JVM crash. Uninstalling both plugins didn't fix. I tried with a new workspace and a blank Eclipse installation, but I eventually had to install my previous Eclipse plugins.

I spent the entire morning trying to fix the mess but I had to restore the previous uncommitted workspace and Eclipse installation, so now I get everything working except for the above error. Ivy worked fine until this morning.

Every Ant task of mine runs in the same JRE as Eclipse (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll` as per `sts.ini`) because I use a lot the `eclipse.refreshLocal` task. While I can workaround the problem by removing/commenting `eclipse.refreshLocal` task **and** run Ant-Ivy tasks in a standard JRE, I'm asking if there is a workaround to get rid of the error, perhaps by deleting a key file in the workspace's metadata.

As I can read, an Ivy method is passed an object that, guessing from its name, is part of Eclipse configuration. While I'll be waiting for a bugfix, my question is how do I investigate more about the nature of this `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1` parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle\[...\]"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077296/an-internal-error-occurred-during-loading-bundle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks related to [Error at building model of new Gradle project for libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26085045/error-at-building-model-of-new-gradle-project-for-libgdx/26109153#26109153) - which includes a workaround that works for Gradle IDE, so maybe it will work for you.

The relevant Eclipse bug is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122

[Edit by OP] to simplify life to people having the same problem I'll post the contents of the link and accept the answer

Just add the following lines to `eclipse.ini`

```
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dosgi.configuration.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area.default=null
-Dosgi.user.area=@user.home
-Dosgi.instance.area.default=null
```

Comment: PS: The relevant underlying Eclipse bug causing this has been fixed in Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2), which according to https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/freeze_plan_4_4_2.php will be released end of Feb (in 1 month from today).

Comment: Confirmed: bug is fixed in [Luna 4.4.2](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20071019155930/uncyclopedia/images/7/7b/Dancing_banana.gif) !