# An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle:........"

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I just downloaded the most recent version of Eclipse Luna, and immediately installed the Aptana 3.0 plugin. After doing this I got a bunch of errors, the same errors as listed in this post:

[An internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle[...]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077296/an-internal-error-occurred-during-loading-bundle)

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-09-27 19:19:23.753 !MESSAGE An
>   internal error occurred during: "Loading bundle:
>   /opt/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/873/0/.cp/bundles/php.ruble".
>   !STACK 0 java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String
>       at org.jruby.util.OSEnvironment.getAsMapOfRubyStrings(OSEnvironment.java:90)
>       at org.jruby.util.OSEnvironment.getSystemPropertiesMap(OSEnvironment.java:75)
>       at org.jruby.RubyGlobal.defineGlobalEnvConstants(RubyGlobal.java:393)
>       at org.jruby.RubyGlobal.createGlobals(RubyGlobal.java:358)
>       at org.jruby.Ruby.init(Ruby.java:1078)
>       at org.jruby.Ruby.newInstance(Ruby.java:186)
>       at org.jruby.embed.internal.SingletonLocalContextProvider.getRuntime(SingletonLocalContextProvider.java:95)
>       at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.runParser(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:166)
>       at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.parse(EmbedRubyRuntimeAdapterImpl.java:93)
>       at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.parse(ScriptingContainer.java:1163)
>       at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1223)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingEngine.getInitializedScriptingContainer(ScriptingEngine.java:292)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.model.ScriptLoadJob.run(ScriptLoadJob.java:76)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.model.AbstractScriptRunner.run(AbstractScriptRunner.java:144)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.model.AbstractScriptRunner.run(AbstractScriptRunner.java:180)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingEngine.runScript(ScriptingEngine.java:274)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.ScriptingEngine.runScript(ScriptingEngine.java:243)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.model.BundleManager.loadScript(BundleManager.java:2032)
>       at com.aptana.scripting.model.BundleManager$BundleLoadJob.run(BundleManager.java:129)
>       at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Apparently there is a fix available for this, a patch can be applied from the updates for Eclipse 4.4. I found the patch Eclipse 4.4.1 Patches for bug 445122   and tried to install it. E4 RCP Patch (bugzillas 445122)    1.0.0   org.eclipse.e4.rcp.R441patch.feature.group  Eclipse.org installed properly, but three others will not installed:

```
 Equinox CORE Feature Patch (bugzillas 445122)  1.0.0
 Equinox CORE SDK Patch (bugzillas 445122)  1.0.0
 Equinox Server CORE Patch (bugzillas 445122)   1.0.0
```

and when I restart Eclipse I am still encountering the same error, it does not appear to be fixed.

Comment: did you find a solution for that? i'm stucked with the same issue..

Comment: Afraid not, I rolled back to Kepler for now, will try again in the future.

Comment: Kepler + Aptana? does it works fine? I keep trying with Luna.. i'll let you know

Answer (score -2):

I found that the patch (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=445122) fixed all of the errors I had installing the Aptana plugin.