# Error message in eclipse "write access not allowed during rendering"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have installed eclipse luna java EE for android development and have installed all the plugins and most of the software available. It was working fine untill today when i got the error while trying to open the **activity_main.xml** - "**write access not allowed during rendering**".

also this is the content of the exception stack trace :
**Exception raised during rendering:** com/android/layoutlib/bridge/impl/RenderSessionImpl

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

also it is worth mentioning that prior to this error i got a blue screen error in windows 8.1, which was "kernel security check failure". after that i did a memory check and found no problem. i have also installed the Genymotion emulator for android and have VT enabled in bios.

could you help me with this? thank you.

Comment: Would help if you showed your code

Comment: it is just a new android application with blank activity. i will update it in the question if you want...

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that the errors are deep within eclipse, and are irrelevant to your application. Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27111765/2398375) may help

Comment: is it possible that i reinstall the eclipse and keep all the plugins and software i have downloaded .  can i copy paste the contents of the plugins folder in eclipse to the newly installed version?  i will keep this as the last resort...

Comment: The software and plugins you have downloaded *could* be what's causing the error, so I wouldn't do so if I were you. Not to mention, when you install a plugin, it may require some settings to be adjusted, which only get adjusted when using an installer; I can't promise that copy and pasting your plugins will work

Comment: i tried installing patches, but nothing worked, so i am installing eclipse again , this time just the java version, and minimum plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i had to reinstall eclipse. The better way is to install each version of eclipse for the specific need and not to install a lot of unnecessary plugins. This according to me is the right way to use Eclipse. 
If anyone has a better solution i would be happy to know it.